# No me funciona clearInterval

Tags: javascript, api, setinterval

Estoy usando fetch dentro de un setinterval, dentro de una variable timer, dentro de un connectedcallback, para traer información de una API cada 3 segundos. El problema es que cuando quiero parar el intervalo, pongo clearinterval(timer), pero no pasa nada, no se para, sino que sigue actualizándose cada 3 segundos.

```
                this.random = this._shadowRoot.querySelector('#random');
                this.killrandom = this._shadowRoot.querySelector('#killrandom');

                var timer = () => setInterval(() => {
                    fetch('https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character/' + Math.floor((Math.random() * 671) + 1) + '/')
                    .then(resp => resp.json())
                    .then(data => {

                    this.name.innerHTML = "Name: " + data.name;
                    this.status.innerHTML = "Status: " + data.status;
                    this.species.innerHTML = "Species: " + data.species;
                    this.type.innerHTML = "Type: " + data.type;
                    this.gender.innerHTML = "Gender: " + data.gender;
                    this.origin.innerHTML = "Origin: " + data.origin.name;
                    this.image.innerHTML = "<img src = '" + data.image + "'>";

                })}, 3000);

                this.random.addEventListener('click', timer);

                this.killrandom.addEventListener('click', clearInterval(timer));
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por favor edita la pregunta para poner el código como texto en lugar de imagen, solo así podemos copiar para probarlo.

Comment: @Triby ya está, gracias por el consejo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estás creando `timer` como una [función flecha](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) y, dentro, generas el intervalo sin asignarlo a una variable, por eso no puedes cancelarlo.

```
var timer = () => setInterval(() => {...}, 3000);
```

Es equivalente a:

```
var timer = function() {
    // No se asigna el intervalo a una variable
    setInterval(() => {...}, 3000);
};
```

Para que no tengas que modificar otras partes de tu código, define una variable global `intervalo`, no es necesario asignar valor, y deja `timer` como función:

```
            // Definir variable global para controlar intervalo
            var intervalo;

            var timer = () => intervalo = setInterval(() => {
                fetch('https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character/' + Math.floor((Math.random() * 671) + 1) + '/')
                .then(resp => resp.json())
                .then(data => {

                this.name.innerHTML = "Name: " + data.name;
                this.status.innerHTML = "Status: " + data.status;
                this.species.innerHTML = "Species: " + data.species;
                this.type.innerHTML = "Type: " + data.type;
                this.gender.innerHTML = "Gender: " + data.gender;
                this.origin.innerHTML = "Origin: " + data.origin.name;
                this.image.innerHTML = "<img src = '" + data.image + "'>";

            })}, 3000);
```

Luego, cuando [asignas un evento](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) no debes poner la función con nombre y paréntesis, porque se ejecutará inmediatamente y no va a ser asignada al evento. Crea una función aparte y asígnala sin agregar paréntesis:

```
function limpiaIntervalo() {
    clearInterval(intervalo);
}

this.killrandom.addEventListener('click', limpiaIntervalo);
```

Aunque también lo puedes lograr usando una función anónima:

```
this.killrandom.addEventListener('click', function() {
    clearInterval(intervalo);
});
```

Comment: el problema es que cuando hago a timer una variable, y no una función flecha, se inicia automáticamente cuando cargo la página, antes de que haga click en el botón correspondiente. Además, tampoco para cuando hago click en el boton killrandom.

Comment: @user255986, listo, modifiqué la respuesta para dejar `timer` como función y asignar el intervalo a otra variable.